# How to loop through files matching variables and display only the file name in bash?

Tags: bash

I need to loop through all the files that match a query and display the file name.

At the moment I can only get it working for all file

```
for filename in ~/notes/*
do
  NAME=`basename "$filename"`
  echo ${NAME%.*}
done;
```

That removes the full path and the file extention, echoing the file name.

I need the same thing but for files that have my query in the file name. I tried this and doesn't return anything

```
for filename in ~/notes/\*$*\* 
do
    TEST=`basename "$filename"`
    echo ${TEST%.*}
done;
```

If I `echo` the `$filename` it does return the full path, but that's not what I need.

Further, the second snippet doesn't return each file in a new line

### How can I get this working?

I have a list of text files, for example:

1. text-file-one
2. another-file-name
3. text-name-file

in terminal I want to type `myfunc name file` and get second and third file.

I tried the following function, but it only searches in sequence.

```
myfunc(){
     for filename in ~/notes/\*$*\* 
       do
         TEST=`basename "$filename"`
         echo ${TEST%.*}
       done;    
}
```

So it would work if I run `myfunc file-name` but not `myfunc file name`

Comment: Too help insure you get a useful answer, you can post several *sample* filenames. It is unclear what you are attempting to match with `~/notes/\*$*\*` which appears to match literal filenames of `'*$unique-name*'`. Post an actual target filename to clear that up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i've nested an **if** loop that uses regex inside the **for** loop.

i left the original filename including extension as the 'file' variable in case you ever want to filter by extension.

just edit the regex variable to capture different kinds of things.

**update:** edited to be able to take two arguments from command line, and to have to match both to print filename

```
    #!/usr/bin/bash

    regex=$1
    regex2=$2

    for filename in ~/notes/*; do
        file=`basename "$filename"`
        filestrip=${file%.*}

        if [[ $filestrip =~ $regex ]] && [[ $filestrip =~ $regex2 ]]; then
            echo $filestrip
        fi

    done
```

Comment: Fantastic. One thing though. I managed to figure out the regex which is close to what I need `.*${*}*.*`. That searches if the **variables** exists in the string **one after the other**. Is there a way to do this: say I have an file `starter-css-snippet.txt` and my variables are `starter css` or `starter snippet`

Comment: honestly i'm not sure what you mean

Comment: can you please read the question again, I added an explanation

Comment: hmm i think i've got it ! note that i think you'll have to add a `regex3=$3` and even `regex4` if you want to add further argument options